# javascript get parent object

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent

In javascript I have set up a listener to a drop down in the DOM.  When my handler fires, i have to remove siblings of the event target.  $(#sometagname).siblings().remove() works, but i won't always know the tag name.  I would rather just get my parent object and call .sibling()remove().  event.target.parentNode.siblings().remove() doesn't work.

When I print out  $(#sometagname)  in an alert popup, I get  [object Object].  When I print   event.target.parentNode  in an alert box, I get [object HTMLCellElement].  How can I get the [object Object]  through some kind of getParent call?  thanks

Comment: If you're using jQuery, what about `.parent()`?

Answer (score 1):

In the event handler, you can use this:
`$(this).parent().siblings().remove();`

Or: `$(event.target).parent().siblings().remove();`

Or: `$(event.target.parentNode).siblings().remove();`